# Foreach and if state to replace end of Character powershell

Tags: string, powershell, if-statement, replace, foreach

I am trying to find a way to replace the characters at the end of an array variable.. tried various ways and had no luck.. here is what I have

```
foreach ($File in $Files){
if ($File.EndsWith(".test"))
{
    #Replaces test with EURTest at the end of the string
    $File2 += $_ -replace "test", "EURTest"

}
elseif ($CanBeRemovedRoamingProfile.EndsWith("CTE"))
{
    # Do nothing 
    $File2 += $File

}
else{
    $File2 += $_ + '.Final'
}
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What results does this produce that are undesirable?  How is `$File2` defined?

Comment: well.. it doesn't seem to work.. it doesn't throw up any errors as wells..  $File2 is just another variable (array) that will hold the new list with correct ending

Answer (score 3):

In...

```
$File2 += $_ -replace "test", "EURTest"
```

...and...

```
$File2 += $_ + '.Final'
```

...you're operating on the [`$_` variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847768.aspx).  `$_` would be used in the [`ForEach-Object` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849731.aspx), whereas inside of a `foreach` loop you should use the loop variable, which is `$File` in this case.